# Compilation error using iBMA.glm from BMA package

Tags: r, compiler-errors, glm

My problem is probably trival (hope), but I haven't found specific help on errors from this package and posts on compilation errors regard issues where people wrote a code themselfs (so they could change it).

I'm trying to replicate first example from example from BMA package help:

```
library(MASS)
library(BMA)
data(birthwt)
y <- birthwt$lo
x <- data.frame(birthwt[,-1])
x$race <- as.factor(x$race)
x$ht <- (x$ht>=1)+0
x <- x[,-9]
x$smoke <- as.factor(x$smoke)
x$ptl <- as.factor(x$ptl)
x$ht <- as.factor(x$ht)
x$ui <- as.factor(x$ui)

### add 41 columns of noise
noise<- matrix(rnorm(41*nrow(x)), ncol=41)
colnames(noise)<- paste('noise', 1:41, sep='')
x<- cbind(x, noise)

iBMA.glm.out<- iBMA.glm( x, y, glm.family="binomial", 
                         factor.type=FALSE, verbose = TRUE, 
                         thresProbne0 = 5 )
summary(iBMA.glm.out)
```

Everything goes fine until `iBMA.glm` function which returns lengthy compilation error which I completely don't understand (I've never compiled anything inside R with my hands):

```
Warning message:
running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="file1b2c792f3888.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="file1b2c792f3888.o"' had status 127 

ERROR(s) during compilation: source code errors or compiler configuration errors!

Program source:
  1: #include <R.h>
  2: #include <Rdefines.h>
  3: #include <R_ext/Error.h>
  4: 
  5: 
  6: /* This is taken from envir.c in the R 2.15.1 source
  7: https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/main/envir.c
  8: */
  9: #define FRAME_LOCK_MASK (1<<14)
 10: #define FRAME_IS_LOCKED(e) (ENVFLAGS(e) & FRAME_LOCK_MASK)
 11: #define UNLOCK_FRAME(e) SET_ENVFLAGS(e, ENVFLAGS(e) & (~ FRAME_LOCK_MASK))
 12: 
 13: 
 14: extern "C" {
 15:   SEXP file1b2c792f3888 ( SEXP env );
 16: }
 17: 
 18: SEXP file1b2c792f3888 ( SEXP env ) {
 19: 
 20: if (TYPEOF(env) == NILSXP)
 21: error("use of NULL environment is defunct");
 22: if (TYPEOF(env) != ENVSXP)
 23: error("not an environment");
 24:  
 25: UNLOCK_FRAME(env);
 26:  
 27: // Return TRUE if unlocked; FALSE otherwise
 28: SEXP result = PROTECT( Rf_allocVector(LGLSXP, 1) );
 29: LOGICAL(result)[0] = FRAME_IS_LOCKED(env) == 0;
 30: UNPROTECT(1);
 31:  
 32: return result;
 33: 
 34:   warning("your C program does not return anything!");
 35:   return R_NilValue;
 36: }
Error in compileCode(f, code, language, verbose) : 
  Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! Warning message:
running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="file1b2c792f3888.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="file1b2c792f3888.o"' had status 127 
In addition: Warning message:
running command 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/x64/R CMD SHLIB file1b2c792f3888.cpp 2> file1b2c792f3888.cpp.err.txt' had status 1
```

My session info is:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Polish_Poland.1250  LC_CTYPE=Polish_Poland.1250    LC_MONETARY=Polish_Poland.1250
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Polish_Poland.1250    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] BMA_3.18.4        rrcov_1.3-8       inline_0.3.14     robustbase_0.92-5 leaps_2.9        
 [6] survival_2.38-3   rJava_0.9-6       relaimpo_2.2-2    mitools_2.3       survey_3.30-3    
[11] boot_1.3-17       MASS_7.3-43      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] mvtnorm_1.0-3   lattice_0.20-33 corpcor_1.6.8   pcaPP_1.9-60    stats4_3.2.2    splines_3.2.2  
[7] tools_3.2.2     DEoptimR_1.0-3  cluster_2.0.3
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. Could you add to your question the output of `sessionInfo()`?